# MapList click: Uncaught ReferenceError: marker is not defined

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have created a toggle to clear my map of all markers. When the toggle is clicked it calls getMapVisit()

I am getting this error when I click the mapList:

Uncaught ReferenceError: markers is not defined

[my source code is here](http://pastebin.com/JsjEaMq3)

How i repair my source code and google API

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code and the error shows 'marker is not defined'. This error is because the variable has not been declared or initialized before you use it in the following code :

```
if(marker){                                   
    marker.setMap(null);
}
```

You need to declare the marker variable at the start of your code.

```
var map;
var marker;
```

The code works after this. Let me know if this works.